# Strange try/catch block behavior

Tags: c#, exception, github, aggregateexception, octokit.net

I am working with Github API via Octokit.net. Now I am writing code that responsible for TwoFactorAuth. When I send request for token, if it is 2FA account, than I must get "TwoFactorRequiredException". I am trying to catch it, but insteand of it I get "AggregateException". But when I look in InnerExceptions of Agg..Exc.. then I have only one, and it is "TwoFactorRequiredException".
Here is my code:

```
try
{
    return client.Authorization.Create(newAuthorization).Result.Token;
}
catch ( Octokit.TwoFactorRequiredException )
{
    _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(TwoFactorAuthPage)}", animated: false);
}
//catch ( AggregateException ex )
//{
//    foreach ( var exception in ex.InnerExceptions )
//    {
//        Debug.WriteLine(exception.GetType());
//    }
//}
```

When it is commented, then I have AggregateExceptions, when it is uncommented, then I have AggExc and inside it I have TwoFactor..Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `client.Authorization.Create(newAuthorization)` returns a `Task<T>`, where `T` is your result type. Inside a `Task`, multiple exceptions can occur, that is why the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `AggregateException` capturing all the exceptions.

Instead of synchronously blocking on an async method, you should `await` on it, which asynchronously waits for it's completion. You gain two things from this. The first is that you don't synchronously block and can free the thread, and the second is that `await` unwraps the exception for you:

```
public async Task<Token> CallSomethingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await client.Authorization.Create(newAuthorization);
        result.Token;
    }
    catch ( Octokit.TwoFactorRequiredException )
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(TwoFactorAuthPage)}", animated: false);
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure what `NavigateAsync` does, I think you may also want to await on it's completion as well.

Comment: Thank you for quick responce.

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov But if I don't need async execution, could it be just fine to catch Aggregate Ex and in it block check it for contain 2FA ex?

Comment: @юрійбабій You could catch the `AggregateException` and iterate it's internal exceptions. Note that synchronously blocking on an async method [can lead to deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), so you should be careful with that.